# Azure Durable Functions - where is the config that points to the durable functions storage account

Tags: azure, azure-durable-functions

I have just created a durable function in the portal directly with:

- Starter function
- Orchestrator function
- Activity function

*The reason I used the portal as I am at home and dont want to down load 4GB of VS 2019 on my home internet.*

Anyway, in the portal I can see my function uses Azure storage to manage its self:

[image]

But, I can't however, find the config that points to this storage account.

I have looked in Kudu and the file system of the function app but I can find anything.

thanks

Comment: Not an answer but you can author functions using visual studio code as well, much more lightweight than vs 2019

Comment: Look at the app settings, you should find some settings related

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find connection string of Azure storage in app settings of function app

Comment: thanks. It was early and I now realise my brain was not in full operation yet. Thanks very much.